# How to build SSRS solutions with TFS vNext

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371766/how-to-build-ssrs-reports-rptproj-with-teamcity-and-visual-studio-2015), except we are not using TeamCity.  The error I receive in TFS is:

> The project file "xyz.rptproj" is not supported by MSBuild
>   and cannot be built.

In our old process (TFS 2013 XAML builds) we had to create a custom build template to call the IDE.  I cannot seem to find a way to do this with TFS 2017.  Is it as easy as having a PowerShell script call it?